# Wrapper function for data.table does not work in local environment

Tags: r, data.table, environment, subset

Consider the following function:

```
test <- function(x,...) {
  # in practical case, it does more
  x[...]
}
```

Then the wrapper function that calls subsetting does not work in a local environment.

```
> library(data.table)
> m <- data.table(x=1:3,key="x")
> m[J(1)]
   x
1: 1
> local({i <- 1; m[J(i)]})
   x
1: 1
> local({i <- 1; test(m, J(i))})
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i' not found
> local({i <- 1; test(m, i)})
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i' not found
```

It is probably because `test()` does not try find symbols in that environment. However, if I change `data.table` to `data.frame` and run the last line, it works fine.

```
> m <- data.frame(x=1:3)
> local({i <- 1; test(m, i)})
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

How can I modify `test()` so that it can work with `...` and subsetting for `data.table`?

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.2   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error, either with `test` or with `[` used in either setting. Using data.table_1.9.2 in R 3.1.0.

Comment: @BondedDust, I'm using data.table_1.9.2 in R 3.1.1

Comment: Write the maintainer.

Comment: @BondedDust, did that: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/776, still waiting for reply.

Comment: Well, ... 9 hours ...you're a rather impatient boy, aren't you now?

Comment: @BondedDust, getting frustrated by environment issues recently :)

Comment: The one thing that seemed out of place was i <- 1 if the environment were supposed to be a data.table. Since I wasn't getting the error I cannot tell whether `:=` would have solved it.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust. If the code in practice is just like this, the walk-around works fine. but `test()` function in practice is actually defined for general purpose (not designed to work only for `data.table` but general objects that support subsetting) and does more things than shown here. In this case, the walk-around seems too ad hoc that may declare dependency on `data.table`.

Comment: @BondedDust Did you maybe have `i` defined in the global environment when you tried to run this?

Comment: The way `[.data.frame` and `[.data.table` work are quite different in terms of practice (use of non-standard evaluation in `data.table`), and the use of statedly missing arguments the difference between `x[i]; x[i,]; x[i,,drop=FALSE]` for data.frames. What will be required will be some approach that sensibly deals with these cases (perhaps different methods for `data.frame` and `data.table`. Your point that data.frame works fine is true in the sense that it doesn't return an error, but it is does not return the same filtering.

Comment: I could well have had a loose i hanging around from some loop or another.

Answer (score 5):

It makes sense that it wouldn't work because the `[...]` for data.table takes an expression that's evaluated in the parent.frame. So in this case `J(i)` would be evaluated in the environment of `test()` since that's where it's called from. Since `test()` is defined in the global environment, any variables not found in `test()` will be searched for in the global environment by default. The `test()` function is not really related to the local environment you've created. You could change the `test()` function to be evaluated in it's parent.frame. For example

```
test <- function(x,...) {
    cc <- match.call()
    cc[[1]] <- quote(`[`)
    names(cc)[2]<-"" #make data.frame happy
    eval.parent(cc)
}
```

Test data

```
library(data.table)
m <- data.table(x=1:3,key="x")    
n <- data.frame(x=1:3)
```

And now the function

```
local({i <- 1; m[J(i)]})
#    x
# 1: 1

local({i <- 1; test(m, J(i))})
#    x
# 1: 1

local({i <- 1; test(n, i)})
#   x
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3

i<-2
test(m, J(i))
#    x
# 1: 2
```

Comment: A great description of the environmental issues.